# Weird question regarding a bit weird VirtualHost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have i weird question regarding a bit weird VirtualHost setup for a server.

My current setup:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/userA/standard/"
        ServerName "server.com"
        ServerAlias *.*.sub.server.com
        Include /home/user.file.lc
        Include /home/common.lc
    </VirtualHost>
```

In the common.lc I have following setup:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.html?q=$1 [L]
    
    <Directory "/var/www">
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
        Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
        Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"

        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

And in the user.file.lc I have the following setup:

```
   VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/%1/standard/"
```

The setup allows several colleagues use the same setup in httpd with just different file structure. This is working really well until today, where we found a strange issue.

Let me elaborate a bit more:

If you visit:

userA.test.server.com -> Everything works perfect.

userB.test.server.com -> Everything works perfect.

But if you visit:
userB.test.server.com/somepage -> The solution responses with the /index.html from userA,  but everything else seems correct. Images, css, JS and so on, are loading from userB. All assets are referred to as root (ex. /dist/file/style.css). Other static files also seems to be loaded correctly.

It seems like that the index.html only loads from userB when no other params are specified.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Probably because you've set `DocumentRoot` to point to `/var/www/html/userA/standard/`  so, where would *you* go if you where a server and no route was defined?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why

```
userB.test.server.com/somepage -> (some other resource "/index.html from userA")
```

is because your rewrite condition says so.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html?q=$1 [L]
```

Also the reason why its always redirecting to userA's homepage is because you specified that the `DocumentRoot` be set to userA's directory

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/userA/standard/"
                             ^ (there)
```

I recommend that you remove this line

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/userA/standard/"
```

because you've already specified a `VirtualDocumentRoot`.

I also recommend that you change

```
'userA' to 'usera'
and 
'userB' to 'userb'
```

The reason being that domain names are **CASE-INSENSITIVE**. It is true that hostnames are (sometimes) **CASE-SENSITIVE** in order to avoid confusion, just make them all lower-case.
Also I tested it out on my own version of Apache 2.2.46 (on linux 4.9.117+ armv7l Android) and found that all uppercase characters are converted to their lowercase rendition in the hostname.

Comment: Hi. I dont get it. The rewriteCond is working, they respond on files directly put in the different folders. But the the RewriteRule /Index.html?q=$ does not. I would guess that it should be responding with whatever.com/abc -> whatever.com/index.html?q=abc. But instead it responds with the original DocumentRoot. When this is removed, (and after fixing faults on the conds) it still not works. 
Its driving me mad...